# How to add every first character from every column?

Tags: java

If a have for example:

```
nem
ava
ma
```

Output would be:

```
nam eva ma
```

This is My code:

```
class Message {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("String without white spaces:");
        String str = s.next();
        str.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        if (str.length() <= 81) {
            System.out.println("in range");
        } else {
            System.out.println("out of range");
        }
        gridStr(str);
    }

    static void gridStr(String str) {
        int l = str.length();
        int k = 0, row, column;
        row = (int) Math.floor(Math.sqrt(l));
        column = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(l));
        
        if (row * column < l) {
            row = column;
        }
        char s[][] = new char[row][column];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                if (k < str.length())
                    s[i][j] = str.charAt(k);
                k++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                if (s[i][j] == 0) {
                    break;
                }
                System.out.print(s[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

This shows only answers for first element of string but not all code for matrix.

Comment: Fix your formatting. Either indent code with four SPACE characters, or surround with triple back-ticks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could do it like this using streams.

- split the string on spaces to create an array.
- stream a large number of ints for string indices
- for each of those, stream the array
- if the index is less than the length of the streamed string, get the character at that index.  Otherwise, return an empty string.
- join into a string.
- and continue doing so until the returned string is empty.

```
String str = "nem ava ma";
String[] strs = str.split("\\s+");

String[] result = Stream.iterate(0, i->++i)
        .map(i -> Arrays.stream(strs)
                .map(s -> i < s.length() ?
                        s.substring(i, i + 1) : "")
                .collect(Collectors.joining()))
        .takeWhile(s -> !s.isEmpty()).toArray(String[]::new);

for (String r : result) {
    System.out.println(r);
}
```

prints

```
nam
eva
ma
```

And here is one way of doing it using for loops

```
// create an array of the words as before.
String str = "nem ava ma";
String[] strs = str.split("\\s+");

// generate an unlimited number of potential columns
for (int col = 0;; col++) { 
    // allocate a StringBuilder in which to build the string
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // iterate thru the array of strings and append the 
    // character at the current column.  If the col is equal to the string
    // length, don't append anything.
    for (String s :strs) {
        if (col < s.length()) {
            sb.append(s.charAt(col));
        }
    }
    // if the stringBuilder is empty, then no more strings
    // can be built so break out of the loop
    if (sb.isEmpty()) {
        break;
    }
    // otherwise, print the string.
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```